# jQuery event object acessible from within anonymous function inside event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been running into some performance issues when a scroll event gets fired on a project i'm working on and found that debouncing the taxing stuff would be a viable solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', debounce(function(e) {
            console.log('debounced');
            console.log(e); // will print the corresponding jQuery object
            // some heavy work
        }, 250, true)
    );
});

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var obj = this, args = arguments;
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
        else if (immediate) func.apply(obj, args);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if (!immediate) func.apply(obj, args);
            timeout = null; 
        }, wait || 100); 
    };
};
```

My question is, how come the jQuery event object is properly handed over within debounce() ?
Isn't it supposed to be passed as first argument of function set as handler, here being debounce() ?

This solution seems to get the job done just fine, but is there some conceptual thing i'm missing here ?

NB: credits to [John Hann](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) for the debouncing function

Comment: Where is `debounceOnce()`?

Comment: Sorry edited, was referring to 'debounce()'. At first was meant because of the fact the debounce got processed multiple times... which, wasn't really what i wanted so tried out different solutions -renaming debounce to debouceOnce in the process- and finally came up with putting debounce directly as event handler.

Comment: The jQuery event object is retrieved from the arguments object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is that jquery event gets return of debounce function, in return it has anonymous function so it exacly what event want to get in parameters.

```
var exampleFunc=function(){
    return 1;
};

var a = exampleFunc; //a is exampleFunc reference
a= exampleFunc(); // a is return value of exampleFunc = 1
```

Some examples the same behavior:

```
$('el').on("click",function(e){ /* do something */ })
```

is the same as

```
someFunc=function(){ /* do something */ };
$('el').on("click",someFunc);
```

and is the same:

```
someFunc=function(){ /* do something */ };
someFunc2=function(){ /* do something 2 */ return someFunc;  };

$('el').on("click",someFunc2());
```

and ... the same as:

```
someFunc2=function(){ 
  /* do something 2 */ 
  return function(){ /* do something */ }  
};

$('el').on("click",someFunc2());
```

Conclusion - using function in next function is using its return value.

```
var a=5;
var getA(){ return 5; };

var twentyfive=a*getA(); //25
```

Some example of using function return as another function:

```js
//EXAMPLE NESTED FUNCTION
var funcNested=function(){ 
  console.log("It is funcNested "); 
};

var func=function(){ return funcNested; };

$("#test").on("click",func());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!
I understood that but somehow struggled to relate how that applies to this case